# how to get param in DSL Script in Jenkins seed job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

When creating seed job, I want to use a String Parameter(job_name) as my job name in DSL Script. But I got a error after building it,

> hudson.model.Failure: ‘$’ is an unsafe character

How to get param in DSL Script?

```
freeStyleJob('$job_name'){
......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use double quotes for string interpolation.

```
freeStyleJob("${job_name}") {
  ...
}
```